# How do I prevent my team from 'grr'ing on Wii Sports Baseball?

Tags: wii-sports

When playing baseball on level 0, my team usually manages to drop the baseball when they catch it, allowing the opposing team to get a (really undeserved) single or double off of us. On the other end of the story, they (skill level 78) rarely drop the ball.

Is there some secret control or button I should press when my team is about to catch a baseball so we don't drop (grrr) it?